# Read in all Groupchats from Skype

Tags: c#, skype, skype4com

i was wondering if anybody knows how i can read in all groupchats of a currentuser using Skype4Com. This is my codes for reading in friends:

```
foreach (SKYPE4COMLib.User myFriends in skype.Friends)
{
    listBox3.Items.Add(myFriends.Handle);
}
```

and then i tried this for groups:

```
foreach (SKYPE4COMLib.Group chat in skype.Groups)
{
    listBox3.Items.Add(chat.ToString());
}
```

but that just printed out:

> System.__COM

any ideas?

Comment: Disclaimer: My only experience in working with Skype data is through directly reading from the SQLite `main.db` database, so I wrote my own Skype wrapper. The `Group` object doesn't actually store the messages. The messages are stored in the `Messages` database table (which I'm sure `SKYPE4COMLib` has a wrapper for) and have a relational link to the `Group` rows. The text contents of the message are stored in the `bodyXml` column of the table I believe, so look for something like that.

Comment: @Dafuqisthis did you figure this out. I'm looking to incorporate a chat window in my c# app and read other users chat content.